# How to remove \n at the end of each value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

I want to make the input such that the user will type a separate number on each new line. I managed to put together this code

```
def str2arr(str):
    arr = []
    for line in str:          
        arr.append(str.replace('\n', ''))
    return arr
import sys
a = sys.stdin.readlines()
print(a)
```

It is working nearly as I would like to, but the output looks like

```
['6543\n', '6543\n', '7654\n']
```

Is there a clever way to remove the \n?
And also, will I even get an usable integers using this method?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: You never call your function

Comment: @Sayse is right a = str2arr(sys.stdin.readlines())

Comment: convert string to int using `int('123')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
a = ['6543\n', '6543\n', '7654\n']
integers = list(map(int, a))
print(integers)
# [6543, 6543, 7654]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [string.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip). That should provide the expected result.

You'll then have to call `int()` on each of the entries in the list.

Example:

```
>>> t = ['6543\n', '6543\n', '7654\n']
>>> [int(x.strip()) for x in t]
[6543, 6543, 7654]
```

Comment: `int()` doesn't mind the trailing `\n`s, so the `strip()` isn't really necessary.

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware of that!

Comment: Apparently trailing whitespace is OK — definitely convenient.